# How can my puny naked apes possibly become the dominant species?

Tags: evolution, fantasy-races

I have been building my fantasy world for the last fifteen years. The world has satirical elements. In particular the world is ruled by puny naked upright apes. I am having difficulty justifying this from an evolutionary point of view.

The world has five major continents with a wide range of biomes. There are many dangerous predators weighing up to one tonne and many dangerous herbivores up to ten tonnes.

It is a low-fantasy setting. Magic manifests primarily as a lack of understanding of the afterlife, and through visions some people have in their sleep. These visions are occasionally prophetic but just as likely to be gobbledygook. And there is no easy way to force yourself to have visions.

The apes are up to six feet long with two arms and two legs. Despite being apes, they have no tail or opposable digits on the feet. This makes them bad climbers. On top of that, they stand upright so are easy to spot from a distance.

To make up for their physical frailty, the apes have an enlarged cranium and brain. They are smarter than their predators and prey. But I feel like this is simply not enough to give them an edge. How can an enlarged brain let my puny apes become the dominant species?

Having a big brain carries downsides. For example the space the brain occupies could be used to anchor jaw muscles. So the apes cannot bite hard enough to kill their prey or suck the marrow from bones. The brain will also require a lot of calories to maintain. Their hands are dexterous but feeble and sensitive, with broad flat nails. No use for digging up roots or clawing an animal to death.

Childbirth will be perilous. With such a big head, fitting through the birth canal and pelvis will be dangerous for mother and child. I have not solved this issue yet.

With such puny claws and teeth, the apes cannot be pure carnivores. At the same time, they are too small to fit a proper fermentation chamber like a cow or gorilla. So I guess they must be omnivores. But not especially good omnivores either.

Overall it seems the apes have a raw deal. Becoming the dominant species will be harder for the brainy puny apes than for a brawny and dumb ape. They are smart sure, but in the state of nature, is this an advantage at all? When you get jumped by a sabretooth tiger, you cannot use your twelve-times tables to bludgeon the tiger into submission. The tiger doesn't care how smart you are. The tiger eats you. You die.

---

**Edit:**
I am also toying with the idea that some of the apes -- for no fault of their own -- are struck with a cruel deformity. Perhaps one or more of its organs stop working or simply isn't there. Perhaps an organ grows too large and starts eating the other organs. Perhaps the ape has an insatiable appetite and eats dirt and rocks and its own fingernails. Perhaps the ape eats normally but forces itself to vomit after a meal. Perhaps the ape simply refuses to eat. Perhaps the ape finds the company of other apes acutely stressful. Perhaps the ape is unable to read the facial expressions and body language of other apes. Perhaps the ape has an unhealthy fixation on certain body parts, or on some useless piece of trivia about how many beetles of every different type exist in the forest. Also, sometimes an ape just falls down dead for no reason.

Comment: Notwithstanding the date, the help center does *specifically* ask you not to go on a rant instead of asking a question.

Comment: Will this Q&A be part of your worldbuilding product? The species you speak of reminds me of some other I have heard of.

Comment: A lot to all of your description is restating issues that hominids faced. I see minimal world building aspect here. How is this not a real world scenario?

Comment: Wait, this seems very familiar, does this have something to do with HUMANS?

Comment: Our [help] clearly states that question must not be "mindless social fun". You confirmed this was just a pun question for April's fool in the same question you posted and deleted yesterday https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/244760/30492.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Communication! Cooperation! Tools! Clairvoyance!

Their increased brain capacity has allowed for the puny naked apes to communicate their desires and fears to each other as they congregate more effectively in groups. They can make plans for sneaking up on any sabretooth tigers that threaten their tribes, and kill them with tools they made from rubbish they found in the bushes, on the shore, and deep under the ground. They even might find ways to avoid having to risk the lives of themselves or their loved ones altogether, as their tools become more efficient and sophisticated.

Taking this speculation further, they might start to develop larger communities, and improve the ways in which they cooperate. Maybe they'll find out what makes these sabretooth tigers, other predators, and ultimately all other animals tick, and befriend them, or find ways to hunt together for species that are simply too silly to befriend.

As this species involves, and their strange cranial enlargement evolves to allow for increasingly more brain activity and cerebral functions, it might be able to figure out which dreams are gobbledygook, and which are precognition, and become completely unfailing in all their endeavours.

To be honest, I wouldn't be surprised if they become too successful for their own good.